# Setting all <input> values to the same thing multiplied by something else

Tags: angularjs

I am writing a small application that converts currencies. This application consists of multiple input fields, which should all be equal, and multiplied by a specific rate. So far I have been using the following, **which works**:

index.html

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currencies.value"></input> //input field
<div>{{currencies.value * currency.rate}}</div> //output fields, many of these
```

app.js

```
app.controller('CurrencyController',function($scope){
    this.currencies = currencies;
    this.value = 1.00;
});
```

However, this is not what I am trying to do. The problem with this is, that only one input field is being used, while the output fields are divs. What i am trying to accomplish is that all of the input, and output fields would be , as so (rate is predefined by a loop):

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currencies.value * currency.rate"></input> //input field
<input type="number" ng-model="currencies.value * currency.rate"></input> //output field, many of these
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to multiply the values of the input field using `ng-model`, since it only sets a value, not a function.

Am I missing something here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-change (add a parent 'currency' to model for good practise')

```
<input type="number" ng-model="currency.input" ng-change="update('output', 'input', currency.rate)"/>
<input type="number" ng-model="currency.output" ng-change="update('input', 'output', 1/currency.rate)"/>
```

Your controller should look like

```
//Initialize the current object
$scope.currency = {
    input: 0,
    output: 0,
    rate: 1.5
}

$scope.update = function(newVal, val, rate){
    $scope.currency[newVal] = $scope.currency[val] * rate;
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/P1NGdvEuvfnqOGhx2OxP?p=preview

Comment: I was not aware of the ng-change tag, thank you! Worked like a charm!